# GARCH-M model estimation in R

Tags: r, time-series

is it possible to estimate a GARCH with volatility in the mean using R?

I read that it may be possible with rgarch package but I have some trouble installing it. Is there any other way?

The model is:

```
  r[t] = mu + c*s[t]^2 + a[t],

  a[t] = s[t]*e[t],

  s[t]^2 = alpha0 + alpha1 * a[t-1]^2 +  beta1 * s[t-1]^2,
```

Regards,

Juan.

Comment: instead of looking for a new package, why don't you tell us what the problem was while installing the rugarch package.

Answer (score 1):

Ruey Tsay has published a [garchM function](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/bs41202/sp2013/garchM.R). Save the code and load it into R using the source function:

```
source('/path/to/garchM.R')
```

The garchM function can be used as follows:

```
data <- read.table('/path/to/data.txt')
returns <- data$rtn * 100
garchM(returns)
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, you can estimate this models with `rugarch` package:

```
returns <- data$rtn * 100

spec = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1),   submodel = "GARCH"), 
      mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), 
     include.mean = TRUE, archm = TRUE, archpow = 2))
#print(spec)

garchm <- ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = returns , solver = 'hybrid')
print(garchm)
coef(garchm)
```

See the help for more information.