# How do estimate GARCH-M in state space form in R or Python language?

Tags: python, r, kalman-filter, state-space, fgarch

I need to estimate GARCH-M in state space form to find time varying risk aversion. The model is this:

[image: GARCH-M in state space form]

Where r is the return of any asset. 
     I tried to estimate this model in [Eviews](http://forums.eviews.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2769#p9297), using Kalman filter, for the return of any asset, but the model always returns an error. There is an error in EViews that it can't estimate a state space model with nonlinear errors in state equation.

My questions are :

1 - There is a way to linearize this model ? 
2 - In this case, I tried use Kalman Filter as in [Chou and Engle, 1992](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0304407692900708). But there are other aproaches ? 
3 - There is a R or Python library to estimate this model ?

I see a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174445/garch-m-model-estimation-in-r) here  but the link, to a possible library, that the individual who answered the question provided does not work.

I apreciate any help.